# How to get the width of a Coarse curve in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

the curve may have a lot of noise around, like this:

[image]

how can I get the width of this curve

PS: although the intensity of the noise may low than the curve, we can't remove them first.

thank you very much!!

Comment: The problem is how to _define_ it, rather than how to get it

Comment: Something to try.  Threshold the image so that you have a single stroke, then use `regionprops` and extract the `MinorAxisLength` property.  I'm not writing an answer because I don't know if it'll work, but it's something you can try.

Comment: Is the width the same everywhere?

Comment: No, we need the large width or the average one. by the way, if the width is same, do you have any idea to solve it?